# JQuery - Hiding/Showing checkbox(s) & Image highlight/border(s)  

Tags: jquery

I'm learning jquery in my spare time to help improve my website making skills.  I thought this was an easy fix, however after spending hours trying to get it working, I've resorted to asking for some or any help.

Background Info:

I am coding a simply form using jquery.  It's a form used to order car parts.  There is a checkbox, that when clicked, reveals 4 other 'extra' choices, each with a small thumbnail, text & checkbox of their own.  The way I want it to work is, the extra choices (their image, text, checkbox) should not appear unless the user has checked the checkbox 'extra choices'.  And once the extra choices checkbox is unchecked, the revealed choices should disappear.

I have the above working part working.  The part I'm stuck on is when the user chooses an extra choice (such as tire, muffler, etc.), I want the border around the image to highlight.  I have a css class called 'img.selected' that I intended to use to visualize the border being highlighted.  So what I know I need to do, but can't figure out, is to reference the css class using jquery.  When the image thumbnail is selected it should highlight and the opposite is true, when deselected via the checkbox, the highlight/border should disappear.

Here is the code I used for the hiding/showing of the extra parts choices:

```
    $("#extraPartsContainer").hide();    /* Hidding by default textbox */
$('#chkWantsExtraParts').click(function() {  /* This will check that checkbox is       clicked */
     if( $(this).is(':checked') ) { /* checking checkbox is checked or not */
         $("#extraPartsContainer").show(); /* showing hide div if checkbox is checked */
     } else {
            $("#extraPartsContainer").hide(); /* hiding div if checkbox is unchecked */
     }
});
```

Any ideas?  I was thinking maybe a simple toggleClass would work.  Or using .hide() .show() again?

Comment: This is as close an example I could find with regards to what I'm trying to accomplish.  The difference being is instead of the radio-buttons high-lighting, it should be the image(s).  It could be just 1 image or any combination of 4.  http://dev-tips.com/featured/jquery-tip-how-to-select-radiocheckbox-input-on-click

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery function addClass() to add a class to an element. e.g.

```
   $('#yourimg').addClass('img.selected');
```

and the corresponding removeClass() will remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking something like this

http://api.jquery.com/even-selector/

**:even Selector**

or jquery `.toggle()`

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

i dont read your entire story:-(

Answer (score 0):

You will use a CSS class to control the border for the image. Your class will add the border to the image when it is applied.

To add or remove the class, you can use jQuery's addClass() and removeClass():

```
$( '#theImage' ).addClass('highlightBorder');
$( '#theImage' ).removeClass('highlightBorder');
```